Should we sometimes let a criminal confess in exchange for no penalties
Let us assume there is a murder case. The court after investigation sentences a man, who in reality is not a murderer, to death. An innocent person is going to be executed while the real criminal is free. Maybe (after there is a final court decision) we should give an option for a real criminal to confess. He will not be given any penalties. He will remain free. In that way we don't execute the real criminal, but we at least don't murder the innocent person. It seems to be a good deal, but that means we have to let a killer be on freedom. Should this procedure be allowed?

I don't think you understood the question

The main problem I see is it gives a way for real murderers to avoid punishment by having an accomplice give a false confession to their crime.

No, this has nothing to do with what I'm asking. Maybe try reading the question first before answering it next time.

It is a good idea, but with  a caveat.  If such a procedure were allowed than any murderer who wanted to go free would simply hire someone else to confess after his conviction. If that person is guilty then the real murderer  clearly isn't so he would need to be acquitted. The other person would face no penalty for his confession and  just collect his check from the murderer. Therefore it should only be allowed if the one confessing can prove his guilt beyond  reasonable doubt.  Along with a potential penalty if he can't bring some reasonable external evidence of his own guilt.
Realistically   speaking however,  if such a procedure existed it would make almost no difference to anyone . It is very difficult to establish the level of proven guilt required to give someone the death penalty. For someone else to  confess and (1) then prove his own guilt, which (2)  by extension would require disproving all the other evidence that has proven the convicted person is the guilty one  would be a  very high bar to scale.
The concern mentioned in the OP of letting a murderer go free isn't really a concern. He would have gone free anyway. Say the innocent person is killed. The case would now be closed. The murder would never be convicted anyway. At least now that he has come forward and confessed his guilt, the public knows to be wary and stay from him

Where would have you been the entire trial  the OP refers  to when the innocent guy  was getting convicted? It is very unlikely someone would get the death penalty had you shown up with evidence against someone else

I didn't say it was well thought through...

Thank you for your answers. I didn't see the obvious option for the killer to bribe someone to make a confession, which seems to make this procedure a lot more complicated. But still. If the person confessing is able to show evidence that puts the court's decision under question, it gives an opportunity to at least reconsider. It makes us a lot of more work to do because the killer has to prove this beyond any reasonable doubt. Even though it gives us a chance to save a person's life, so maybe introducing such procedure would be worth the effort.
